# How to run MS access append query from another query

Tags: ms-access

I have created one append query "query1" as under

```
INSERT INTO TH ( ID, [No], [Date] )
VALUES ([@ID], [@NO], [@Date]);
```

One third party software allows to run SQL statements, for which we tried to use following query which is not working

```
EXEC Query1 '1','111','2016-04-01';
```

and

```
EXEC Query1 @ID='1',@NO='111',@Date='2016-04-01';
```

Both are not affecting any data

What is the correct method to use the same?

Comment: What is the third-party software and what does their documentation say about the syntax of the EXEC statement? Does your MS Access query work properly when you run it from the MS Access query designer?

Comment: You seem to be using SQL Server syntax (`EXEC` is to run stored procedures) for Access, this is not going to work.

Comment: then how will it work? it i click on Query1 in access it ask for parameter values and on giving the same it accepts the value

Comment: Please provide specifics such as @nicomp's questions. Your syntax is TSQL, not supported natively in MS Access unless you use a pass-through query to SQL Server. How are you running the SQL statement: in stored query or VBA? Do you connect to MSSQL?